# In Python, How to apply round() on a list type output?

Tags: list, python-3.8

I am trying to write a program that converts temperatures from Celsius to Fahrenheit.

```
temps = [("Los Angeles", 26)]

def c_to_f(data):
    return (data[0], (9 / 5) * data[1] + 32)


print(list(map(c_to_f, temps)))
```

The output is: `[('Los Angeles', 78.80000000000001)]`
I do not need all that number, it is enough for me to be just like `[('Los Angeles', 78.8)]`

I tried to use the round() function as:

```
print(list(round(map(c_to_f, temps), 2)))
```

I got `"TypeError: type list doesn't define __round__ method"`

So, is there a way to get my desirable output? By round() or something else?

Comment: `[(place, round(temp * 9 / 5 + 32, 2)) for place, temp in temps]`. In general, I would recommend writing a function that handles nothing but temperature conversion, because it makes things a lot more straightforward. So you will end up with `[(place, round(c_to_f(temp), 2)) for place, temp in temps]`

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `round()` in `c_to_f` function

```
def c_to_f(data):
    return (data[0], round((9 / 5) * data[1] + 32, 2))
print(list(map(c_to_f, temps)))
```

**Output:**

```
[('Los Angeles', 78.8)]
```

Comment: That's it. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions to loop through and round.

`print([(place, round(temp, 2)) for place, temp in map(c_to_f, temps)])`

This code goes through the map, one by one, and adds a tuple to the list containing the name and rounded temperature.

**Output:**

`[('Los Angeles', 78.8)]`

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. 
But I think it is less readable in comparison with @deadshot answer.

Comment: I agree; list comprehensions are hard to read and confusing. I still, however, make a point of recommending them as an integral part of the Python architecture. Quoting another Stack Overflow answer: *"And this is python."*